# Send AT Commands to Android Phone

Tags: android, at-command

I want to Send AT Command to Android phone.

I know SDK does not support this.

but there are two solution :

1. change the code of Kernel and release your new Android (it seems it is so hard!)
2. LoopBack on `USB`.(i think Bluetooth is same)

About second solution , when you connect your phone to PC with `USB` cable , you will see a `GSM` modem on Device Manager that help you to send AT Command to `GSM` Modem.

If we find a solution to loop back on mobile phone , we can send AT commands to GSM Modem.

Question is : HOW to loop back and what tty file on kernel will help us?

Comment: see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308130/using-android-emulator-to-test-at-commands-by-com-from-external-application/10314862#10314862

Comment: About solution 1, I wonder *where* (in which files of the kernel) is the AT command "manager" within the open source Android?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

first you have to root the phone then
in adb shell

> su
>
> echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0

if you want to see answer use

> cat /dev/smd0

i've test this command in samsung mini,cooper,s+ and it works.

if you use htc (htc rhyme tested) try to adb shell and type this command "radiooptions 13 AT"
if you want to see answer type "logcat -b radio"

try echo to /dev/smd0 for other devices

*you can use this command in sdk java code by using Runtime.exec (require su)

Comment: thanks... it worked.
but the problem is just AT\r worked and other commands like atd123456789 does not work.

Comment: try ATD123456789;\r (add ; at the end of phone number) i tested and it works on samsung.and i think it works for all of mobile

Comment: you are correct, atd123456789 is a data call that does not support with the phone i checked.
thanks for your answer and regard.

Comment: The above works, but using `cat /dev/smd0 &` before the AT command is better, since sometimes the `cat` command lock up the device, in case the shell TERM is using CTS/DSR as a serial control signals.