# Initiate CSD data call from Android app

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I need to initiate a Circuit Switched Data (CSD) call from my android app in order to communicate with some legacy hardware.

Is this possible - if so, would you be able to give me a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
you can use at command in android with below trick :
[Send AT Commands to Android Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284067/send-at-commands-to-android-phone)

with  atd0********** you can make data call.