# How to run AT command by programming in android.?

Tags: at-command

I'm new with AT commands! Any one please help!

I want to get Network related information which is not available in Android Software Developer Kit. Please also tell me where the collection of this commands are available for android phones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send AT Commands to Android Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284067/send-at-commands-to-android-phone)

Comment: Standard GSM/UMTS/LTE AT commands are available at http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm.  There is a similar spec for SMS AT commands.  How to use AT commands on Android has been asked and answered before on SO, just look at the related questions on the right hand side of your screen.