# Android - Need help to get frequency band

Tags: android, frequency

I'm trying to find the current frequency band.

I read a lot on this issue in the past few days but I didn't found anything.
I need solution for it (code not an app).

If I can access to this data by getting root access it is also OK.

Comment: Please specify what "frequency band" do You mean? Is that GSM frequency band?

Comment: I need to know if i'm on 2g 850/900/1800/1900 or 3g 2100/1900/1700/850/800 or FDD-LTE 2100/1900/1700/850/2600/900/800/700 or TDD-LTE 2600/2300/2500/3500/700

Comment: Did you get any solution? Could you share your code

Answer (score 1):

For network type You can use this method (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25912464/6950238)):

```
public static String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);      
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(info==null || !info.isConnected())
        return "-"; //not connected
    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
        return "WIFI";
    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        int networkType = info.getSubtype();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: //api<8 : replace by 11
                return "2G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: //api<9 : replace by 14
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:  //api<11 : replace by 12
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:  //api<13 : replace by 15
                return "3G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:    //api<11 : replace by 13
                return "4G";
            default:
                return "?";
         }
    }
    return "?";
}
```

But to get frequency You should work directly with GSM module of phone via AT Commands like `AT!BAND?` for [Sierra](https://www.sierrawireless.com/resources/documents/support/2130617_supported_at_command_reference-v2.4.pdf) modules or `AT+CBAND?` for [other](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcband-get-and-set-the-mobile-operating-band/). It's also possible, but with hard way like [this](https://afewe.wordpress.com/android-arm-development/working-with-the-radio-layer-interface-ril-in-android/). Or may be something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133631/6950238) but it hardly ever.