# How to command an android phone using AT commands sent by Bluetooth from a Delphi application?

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth

How to command an android phone using AT commands sent by Bluetooth from a Delphi application ?

Background:

Older phones (such as Sony Ericsson K600i) are typically able to accept AT commands from:

1. a data cable
2. a Bluetooth connection
3. an IRDA connection

But, At first it seems that android phones do not offer the same kind of commandability by Bluetooth / AT commands.

However, I was surprised to learn that actually there MUST BE a way to order an android phone to make a call using Bluetooth.

How do I know this?

Well: A car navigator (Garmin Camper 660) is able to use a Bluetooth connection to an android phone and the navigator is then able to initiate a voice call (and specify the number to call) after the Garmin Camper 660 has been properly Bluetooth paired with the phone.

So: If a  car navigator can do it, How can I do the same from a Delphi application ?

a side question: How does the Bluetooth pairing work, eg: Do I pair the phone with my PC (on which the Delphi App runs on) or with my Delphi App ?

It could be as simple as use a virtual serial port to send the AT commands, but then I still need two things to make that work:

1. How to find out the proper name of the virtual serial port so I can open it?

and

2. How do I pair properly PC / Phone ?

Comment: As far as I know Bluetooth doesn't work by sending/receiving AT commands but instead has its own protocol for sending/receiving commands and data for that matter. You can read more general principle of how bluetooth connections work on android devices [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#KeyClassesAndInterfaces). As you will read there different devices make use of different bluetooth communication profiles. For what you are trying to do you should focus learning more about Bluetooth HFP (Hands Free Profile)

Comment: You're not going to be able to do it with a non-rooted, standard Android phone. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284067/send-at-commands-to-android-phone and other similar links (hint: use Google)